# Why the reverse is not working ? and how can I add the rotation part?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The post is a bit long but both scripts are connected to each other. I tried to reduce the amount of code.

The Waypoints script is attached to empty GameObject and I added to it a rotation part :

```
[Header("Rotation")]
public Quaternion rotationTothinkWhatToDoHere;
```

but I'm not sure how to use it here in the Waypoints script and in the WaypointsFollower script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Objects To Move")]
    public Transform objectToMovePrefab;
    public int numberOfObjectsToMove = 1;
    public bool moveInReverse = false;

    [Header("Speed")]
    public float speed;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    public float minRandomSpeed = 1;
    public float maxRandomSpeed = 100;
    private bool changeSpeedOnce = false;

    [Header("Rotation")]
    public Quaternion rotationTothinkWhatToDoHere;

    [Header("Waypoints")]
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> waypoints;
    public bool moveOnWaypoints = false;

    [Header("Delay")]
    public bool useDelay = false;
    public float delay = 3;
    public bool randomDelay = false;
    public float minRandomDelay = 0.3f;
    public float maxRandomDelay = 5;

    [Header("LineRenderer")]
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public bool moveOnLineRenderer = false;
    public List<Vector3> lineRendererPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    [Header("Cinemachine Cameras")]
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCamera;

    private List<WaypointsFollower> waypointsFollowers = new List<WaypointsFollower>();

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToMove; i++)
        {
            var parent = GameObject.Find("Moving Object Parent");
            var objectToMove = Instantiate(objectToMovePrefab, parent.transform);
            objectToMove.name = "Platfrom";

            waypointsFollowers.Add(objectToMove.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>());
        }

        virtualCamera.Follow = waypointsFollowers[0].gameObject.transform;
        virtualCamera.LookAt = waypointsFollowers[0].gameObject.transform;

        foreach (WaypointsFollower wpf in waypointsFollowers)
        {
            wpf.goForward = moveInReverse;
        }

        WaypointsMovementStates();

        SpeedUpdater();

        if (useDelay)
            StartCoroutine(SendObjectstomoveWithDelay());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        lineRendererPositions.Clear();
        lineRendererPositions.AddRange(GetLinePointsInWorldSpace());

        SpeedUpdater();
    }

    IEnumerator SendObjectstomoveWithDelay()
    {
        {
            foreach (WaypointsFollower follower in waypointsFollowers)
            {
                if (randomDelay)
                {
                    delay = Random.Range(minRandomDelay, maxRandomDelay);
                }

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

                follower.go = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SpeedUpdater()
    {
        if (changeSpeedOnce == false)
        {
            foreach (WaypointsFollower follower in waypointsFollowers)
            {
                if (randomSpeed)
                {
                    follower.speed = Random.Range(minRandomSpeed, maxRandomSpeed);
                }
                else
                {
                    follower.speed = speed;
                }
            }

            changeSpeedOnce = true;
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        var positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    private void WaypointsMovementStates()
    {
        // If moving on both linerenderer positions and waypoints objects
        if (moveOnLineRenderer && moveOnWaypoints && waypoints.Count > 0)
        {
            if (useDelay == false)
            {
                foreach (WaypointsFollower wpf in waypointsFollowers)
                {
                    wpf.go = true;
                }
            }
        }


        // If moving on linerenderer positions only without moving on waypoints objects
        if (moveOnLineRenderer && moveOnWaypoints == false)
        {
            if (waypoints.Count > 0)
                waypoints.Clear();

            if (useDelay == false)
            {
                foreach (WaypointsFollower wpf in waypointsFollowers)
                {
                    wpf.go = true;
                }
            }
        }


        // If only to move on waypoints objects without moving on linerenderer positions
        if (moveOnWaypoints && waypoints.Count > 0 && moveOnLineRenderer == false)
        {
            lineRendererPositions.Clear();

            foreach (Transform wp in waypoints)
            {
                lineRendererPositions.Add(wp.position);
            }

            if (useDelay == false)
            {
                foreach (WaypointsFollower wpf in waypointsFollowers)
                {
                    wpf.go = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if(moveInReverse)
        {
            foreach (WaypointsFollower wpf in waypointsFollowers)
            {
                wpf.go = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the WaypointsFollower script, this script is attached to each object that moves along the waypoints.
It's working fine if goForward is true but when goFoward is false for some reason the index value is -1 and I'm getting exception out of index was out of range on line 73 :

```
newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, waypoints.lineRendererPositions[index], distanceToTravel);
```

The idea when goForward is false to move the object from the last waypoint to the first waypoint and then when it's reaching the first waypoint then switch the goForward to true and move forward from the first waypoint to the last.

It's working when goFoward is first time true then it's moving from the first waypoint to the last waypoint and then it's moving from the last waypoint to the first one but it's not working when goForward is first time false.

I can't figure out why it's -1

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointsFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Waypoints waypoints;
    public bool go;
    public bool goForward;

    private int index = 0;
    private int counter = 0;
    private int c = 0;
    private List<GameObject> curvedLinePoints = new List<GameObject>();

    public int numofposbetweenpoints;

    private bool getonce;

    private void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.Find("Waypoints").GetComponent<Waypoints>();

        curvedLinePoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line Point").ToList();

        if(waypoints.moveInReverse == false)
        {
            goForward = true;
        }
        else
        {
            goForward = false;
        }

        if(goForward)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            index = waypoints.lineRendererPositions.Count - 1;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (getonce == false)
        {
            numofposbetweenpoints = curvedLinePoints.Count;

            getonce = true;
        }

        if (go == true && waypoints.lineRendererPositions.Count > 0)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;

            // error exception out of bound on line 55 to check !!!!!
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, waypoints.lineRendererPositions[index], distanceToTravel);

            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);

            if (newPos == waypoints.lineRendererPositions[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // when you hit a waypoint:
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= waypoints.lineRendererPositions.Count - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne)
                    {
                        index++;
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;

                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                { // going backwards:
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne)
                    {
                        index--;

                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;

                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your previous post before it was deleted, so here is the answer I had for your original question of moving between waypoints by both rotating and movement with the option of what occurs at the end of the motion. I can answer your current question if answering your last deleted question has still not solved your issue.

Instead of using the `Update` function to handle the rotation and movement between a series of waypoints in a list, I would recommend using a [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). If you are unfamiliar, think of them as a process that handles small increments of work overtime and will jump back where it leaves off. It should simplify the issue of rotation and movement into smaller bite-sized pieces of logic, allowing an easier time to understand your issue.

```
// new enum - outside of your class
public enum WaypointMovementType
{
    REPEAT_START,       // will repeat to the start waypoint when end is reached
    REPEAT_REVERSE,     // will reverse the waypoint list when end is reached
    STOP                // will terminate when end is reached
};

// new variables - this is inside your class

// keep a reference of our coroutine to not run duplicates
Coroutine movingWayPoints = null;

// time it takes to rotate to our goal waypoint
private float rotateTime = 0.5f;

// time it takes to move to our goal waypoint
private float movementTime = 1.5f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    parent = GameObject.Find("Waypoints");

    // generate the waypoints
    GenerateWaypoints();

    // run our process 
    if (movingWayPoints == null)
        movingWayPoints = StartCoroutine(MoveBetweenWaypoints(tmpList, WaypointMovementType.STOP));
}

private IEnumerator MoveBetweenWaypoints(List<Vector3> waypoints, WaypointMovementType movementType)
{
    int currentWaypointIdx = 0;

    // continue our loop until we have reached our end goal waypoint 
    while (currentWaypointIdx < waypoints.Count)
    {
        // rotate towards out goal point
        yield return StartCoroutine(RotateTowardsGoalWaypoint(waypoints[currentWaypointIdx]));

        // move towards our goal point
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveTowardsGoalWaypoint(waypoints[currentWaypointIdx]));

        // increment our index count or wait for further time if you would like a delay between rotation / movement
        ++currentWaypointIdx;
    }

    // coroutine is done, so set the motion to null
    movingWayPoints = null;

    // now that we have reached the end, determine what we want to do
    if (movementType != WaypointMovementType.STOP)
    {
        // if we want to reverse, then reverse our list
        if (movementType == WaypointMovementType.REPEAT_REVERSE)
            waypoints.Reverse();

        // now call the coroutine again
        movingWayPoints = StartCoroutine(MoveBetweenWaypoints(waypoints, movementType));
    }
}

private IEnumerator RotateTowardsGoalWaypoint(Vector3 goalWaypoint)
{
    // store our current rotation
    Quaternion initialRotation = transform.rotation;

    // find our direction to the goal
    Vector3 dir = goalWaypoint - transform.position;

    // calculate the final / goal rotation
    Quaternion finalRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);

    // store our current time
    float currentTime = 0.0f;

    // rotate until we reach our goal
    while (currentTime <= rotateTime)
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(initialRotation, finalRotation, currentTime / rotateTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    // set our rotation in case there are floating point precision errors
    transform.rotation = finalRotation;
}

private IEnumerator MoveTowardsGoalWaypoint(Vector3 goalWaypoint)
{
    // store our current position
    Vector3 initialPostion = transform.position;

    // store our current time
    float currentTime = 0.0f;

    while (currentTime <= movementTime)
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initialPostion, goalWaypoint, currentTime / movementTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    // set our position in case there are floating point precision errors
    transform.position = goalWaypoint;
}
```

The current code uses time instead of speed which can be changed by changing how the `Lerp` steps are inputted. One other issue currently is the repeat backwards will move and rotate to the first element in the reversed list, but this can be fixed by passing in an `index` parameter for where to start in the list.

If you would rather use your current implementation, I can help debug it, but in the future do not delete questions you expect an answer to unless you have a good reason to do so. I should also mention, as your original question had only 1 script, the current script is expecting the object that generates the waypoints is the same object that is moving between them. It would be very easy to fix by creating a new public field that references some other `Transform` that should move between the waypoints, then replace all of the `transform.rotation` and `transform.position` with `yourObject.position` and `yourobject.rotation`.

I should also add, to change how the waypoint movement will function after a single pass is finished, simply change the `WaypointMovementType` parameter to a different value before making the initial call.

Edit: As derHugo mentioned that a speed variant of the answer would better suit the needs of the use case, here is an additional snippet with speed instead of time.

```
private IEnumerator MoveBetweenWaypoints(List<Vector3> waypoints, WaypointMovementType movementType)
{
    int currentWaypointIdx = 0;

    // continue our loop until we have reached our end goal waypoint 
    while (currentWaypointIdx < waypoints.Count)
    {
        // rotate towards out goal point
        yield return StartCoroutine(RotateTowardsGoalWaypoint(waypoints[currentWaypointIdx]));

        // move towards our goal point
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveTowardsGoalWaypoint(waypoints[currentWaypointIdx]));

        // increment our index count or wait for further time if you would like a delay between rotation / movement
        ++currentWaypointIdx;
    }

    // coroutine is done, so set the motion to null
    movingWayPoints = null;

    // now that we have reached the end, determine what we want to do
    if (movementType != WaypointMovementType.STOP)
    {
        // if we want to reverse, then reverse our list
        if (movementType == WaypointMovementType.REPEAT_REVERSE)
            waypoints.Reverse();

        // now call the coroutine again
        movingWayPoints = StartCoroutine(MoveBetweenWaypoints(waypoints, movementType));
    }
}

private IEnumerator RotateTowardsGoalWaypoint(Vector3 goalWaypoint)
{
    // find our direction to the goal
    Vector3 dir = goalWaypoint - transform.position;

    // calculate the final / goal rotation
    Quaternion finalRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);

    // continue until our angles match
    while(Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, dir) > ROTATION_CHECK_EPSILON)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, finalRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
        yield return null;
    }

    // set our rotation in case there are floating point precision errors
    transform.rotation = finalRotation;
}

private IEnumerator MoveTowardsGoalWaypoint(Vector3 goalWaypoint)
{
    // continue until our distance is close to our goal
    while(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, goalWaypoint) > DISTANCE_CHECK_EPSILON)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, goalWaypoint, Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
        yield return null;
    }

    // set our position in case there are floating point precision errors
    transform.position = goalWaypoint;
}
```

Comment: Instead of lerping by time I would rather define a move and rotation speed and use `MoveTowards` and `RotateTowards` .. otherwise even if two waypoints are very close the time will be the same it will just move a lot slower etc

Comment: @derHugo Very true! I'll add an additional snippet that uses speed instead of time for completeness. Definitely agree that speed would have been better here for the use of waypoints.

Comment: @derHugo Added a new example snippet that now uses `MoveTowards` and `RotateTowards`.